# Unsupported operant for a non existent variable?

Tags: python

I am executing the following script:

```
dic1 = {
        1:{2:3,3:1,5:4,6:3,7:5}, 
        2:{1:4,2:1,3:3,5:5,8:2}, 
        3:{1:2,2:1,4:5,8:1}, 
        4:{1:3,3:2,6:5,8:4}
       }

dic2 = {
        1:{2:3,3:1,5:4,6:3,7:5}, 
        2:{1:4,2:1,3:3,5:5,8:2}, 
        3:{1:2,2:1,4:5,8:1}, 
        4:{1:3,3:2,6:5,8:4}
       }

from math import sqrt

def distEuclidea(dic1, dic2):
    suma2 = sum([pow(dic1[elem]-dic2[elem],2)
                 for elem in dic1 if elem in dic2])
    return sqrt(suma2)

def similEuclidea(dic1, dic2):
    return 1/(1+distEuclidea(dic1, dic2))


print (similEuclidea(dic1,dic2))
```

I get the error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "aplicacion_distancia_euclidea.py", line 28, in <module>
    print (similEuclidea(dic1,dic2))
  File "aplicacion_distancia_euclidea.py", line 25, in similEuclidea
    return 1/(1+distEuclidea(dic1, dic2))
  File "aplicacion_distancia_euclidea.py", line 21, in distEuclidea
    for elem in dic1 if elem in dic2])
  File "aplicacion_distancia_euclidea.py", line 21, in <listcomp>
    for elem in dic1 if elem in dic2])
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'dict' and 'dict'
```

I do not understand why it says that I have some operand between dict and dict when I do not have any dict variable in my script.

Comment: What do you think `{2:3,3:1,5:4,6:3,7:5}` is? A dictionary...

Comment: you have just about 8 of them. what do you expect `dic1[elem]-dic2[elem]` does?

Comment: `'dict'` in the error message does not refer to a variable name, it refers to a variable's *type*, hence the error message "**TypeError**: unsupported operand **type(s)** for -: 'dict' and 'dict'".  Also, "operand" in this case is referring to the minus symbol (`-`).  It's saying you can't subtract one dictionary from another.  In other words, Python can't do `{2:3,3:1,5:4,6:3,7:5} - {2:3,3:1,5:4,6:3,7:5}`.`

Comment: @StevenRumbalski Post that as an answer, man!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`dict` is the type of the variable, not the variable itself. What the error means is that you are trying to substract a dict from another dict:

```
suma2 = sum([pow(dic1[elem]-dic2[elem],2)
```

You should take a value from the dictionaries inside `dic1` and `dic2` for that, use:

```
dic1[elem][something_else]

dic2[elem][something_else]
```

Something else can be:

- If elem is 1: 2,3,5,6,7
- If elem is 2: 1,2,3,5,8
- If elem is 3: 1,2,4,8
- If elem is 4: 1,3,6,8

At least according to the inner `dict`s.